# visiting page on ftp server using php

Tags: php

I have a php file on FTP server called 'file.php'.
I need to execute this file and I can do it by visiting page 'www.website.com/file.php'.
But I want this to happen automatically and I'm planning to use windows task scheduler, but for task scheduler I need a (.bat) file with script in it to visit that page.
Ive tried curl :

```
$ch = curl_init("http://www.website.com/file.php"); curl_exec($ch);
```

but it doesn't execute the php file.
I need this script located on my local machine
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: title might be wrong.

Comment: No idea what this has to do with `ftp`, but anyway: requesting a url by means of a curl call _will_ execute the script, since you send an ordinary http request. So if you are right that calling the URL from within a browser _does_ execute the script and a request via _curl_ does not, then your curl request fails.

Comment: so you say it should work?

Comment: Check the answer to the similar question here:
http://superuser.com/questions/321215/how-can-i-open-a-url-on-a-schedule-in-the-default-browser

Comment: Certainly sending an http request to a http server will work the same, regardless by what means you send the http request. So question is: why does your curl request fails? We cannot tell you without you posting more information. Like: _what error do you get_?

Comment: There is no error(cmd just flashes and closes).   If i take the .bat file code and put it in .php file it works but in .bat file it doesnt. Is it possible that server dont let me use curl on it? However prasad DLV answer will work for me.